# how to compare each and every element with other element of two multi dimensional arrays in verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I want to compare two multi dimensional arrays with each element of one array with the other array. What is the procedure to make it possible?

```
timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date:    09:21:01 01/08/2015 
// Design Name: 
// Module Name:    FACTORISING_INTEGER 
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool versions: 
// Description: 
//
// Dependencies: 
//
// Revision: 
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments: 
//
module FACTORISING_INTEGER(
    input [15:0] f,g,
    //output reg [15:0] b,c,
     output reg [15:0]mem,
     //output reg [15:0]memc[15:0],
    input clk
    );
reg [15:0]memb[15:0];
reg [15:0]memc[15:0];
reg [15:0] b,c ;
integer address;     
integer i,j;
always@(posedge clk)
  begin

   for(i=1;i<=f;i=i+1)
     begin
        if(f % i == 0)
         begin
          $display("%b is the factor of f ",i);
          #100;

           b<=i;
            memb[i]<=b;
            end
       end 
   for(j=1;j<=g;j=j+1)
     begin  
     if(g % j == 0)
         begin
          $display("%b is the factor of g ",j);
          #100;

           c<=j;
            memc[j]<=c;
            end
      end
    end 

always@(posedge clk)
   begin
    for(address=0;address<16;address=address+1)
     begin
      if(memc[address]==(memb[address]))
#100      
         mem[address]<=memb[address];
        else if(memb[address]>(memc[address]))
        #100
           mem[address]<=memb[address];
        else if(memc[address]>(memb[address])) 
        #100
             mem[address]<=memc[address];

         end

      end


endmodule
```

Comment: There's only a few explanations for why an asker wouldn't look at the preview of their question before posting. None of them is a positive reflection on the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, some major mistakes need to be pointed out:

- Never use blocking delays in synthesizable code. Remove the `#100`. If you what to put delay between operations, then create an FSM.
- A synthesizable for-loop must static unroll. This means the number of loops must be constant. The `f` is an input so `for(i=1;i<=f;i=i+1)` should be

  ```
  for(i=1;i<16;i=i+1) begin // <-- static loop
    if (i <= f) begin // dynamic condition
      // ... your code here
    end
  end
  ```
- Non-blocking assignments (`<=`) will update the value in a later stage in the Verilog scheduler (this is used to protect agents hold-time violations). With the code `b<=i; memb[i]<=b;`, `memb[i]` will be assigned the old value of `b` not the value it was just assigned. Often in an edge sensitive always block all assignments use non-blocking, however this practice is only needed for signals that will be synthesized to flops (i.e. D-flip-flips and latches). There are three ways to resolve this:

  - `b = i; memb[i]<=b;` Immediate assignments to `b`. This assumes `b` in only an intermediate signal. This is not common practice, but it is legal and synthesizable.
  - `memb[i]<=i;` assign `i` to `memb[i]`
  - `memb[i]<=i[15:0];` Like above but no range warning **Best**

---

## Now to the actual question: (how to compare)

The main key to doing any comparison (such as finding a max value) is to use is to use conbinational logic.

```
// Find max
always @* begin
  mem = 16'h0; // initial default value
  for(address=0; address<16; address=address+1) begin
    if (mem[address] <= memb[address]) mem[address] = memb[address];
    if (mem[address] <= memc[address]) mem[address] = memc[address];
  end
end
```

If you want to flop the value (good idea if the result is an output), then I'd suggest renaming the above `mem` to `next_mem` or `mem_next` (or any other meaning full name), then add a sequential clocking assignment:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  mem <= next_mem;
```